# How do I get my discord.js bot to remove a role when a reaction is removed?

Tags: bots, discord.js

I have a code that allows a user to add a reaction to get a role. However, I want my bot to remove the role if a reaction is removed, and I don't know how to do that. Here is my current code.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const keepAlive = require('./server');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.author !== null && message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.toString().toLowerCase().includes('start reaction roles')) {
        message.delete()
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('React to get notified')
            .setDescription(`Hello! Please react to this message to get a role. Here are the roles that you can get by reacting:\n>  | React with this emoji to get <@&727665971443269635> notifications.\n> ⚠️ | React with this emoji to get <@&727633811709362187>.\nYou can chose one of the emojis, or both of them.\n\n**NOTE:**\nCurrently, this command does not support removing your roles. If you want to remove your role, click on the emoji. Then, click on your profile, and click the X next to the role you want to remove. You can always get it back by reacting.`)
        message.channel.send(embed).then(sentMessage => {
            sentMessage.react("").then(() => sentMessage.react("⚠️")).then(() => {
                const filter = (reaction, user) => {
                    return true;
                }
                const collector = sentMessage.createReactionCollector(filter);
                collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
                    if (reaction.emoji.name === ''){
                        role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "ne1 here");
                        message.member.roles.add(role);
                    }
                    else if (reaction.emoji.name === '⚠️'){
                        role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "HR notifications");
                        message.member.roles.add(role);
                    }
                })
            })
            .catch(() => console.error('One of the emojis failed to react.'));
        })
    }
});

keepAlive();
client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

If someone could tell me how to do this, that would be great.

Comment: You'll have to listen for the `messageReactionRemove` event and use partials to fetch the message where the reaction was removed.  

https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html
https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/blob/master/docs/topics/partials.md

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this with only discord.js, couldn't find anything about this in de documentation. But you could try to use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reaction-role) npm module. And use the [documentation](https://reactionrole.bariscodes.me) of the npm module. I think that is faster and easier.

Hope I helped.